# ¿Cómo obtener una lista de objetos que forman parte de un objeto en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Tengo una relación N a N entre T1 y T2 y una relación N a 1 entre T2 y T3 de tal forma que un T2 tiene N T3.

Yo quiero retornar una lista de T1 que contengan a los T2 y T3 para posteriormente crear una tabla en la vista.

```
    $listaT1= T1::where('id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
    $T2 = T1::with('columnas')->get(); //Esto me incluye la lista de T2
```

¿Cómo hago para indicarle que por cada T2 me traiga los N T3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues tu consulta sera similar a que ya tienes,pero:

1.- quitemos el `where('id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail()`, dado que es lo mismo que `findOrFail($id)`.
2.- unamos las dos consultas que tienes para quedarnos conuna sola:

```
$result = T1::with('T2')->findOrFail($id);
```

3.- Agrega la relacion de T2 a T3

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class T2 extends Model
{
    
    public function T3()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\T3');
    }
}
```

(La implementacion es solo un ejemplo)
4.- por ultimo agregar la relacion en la consulta:

```
$result = T1::with('T2.T3')->findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo que realmente faltaba era "T2.T3" porque las relaciones entre los objetos ya estaban definidas (aunque no lo mencioné).